# удаление элементов из массива php

Tags: php

как можно удалить элементы массива от начала до указанного?
например, есть массив:

```
Array (
    [title] => 
    [keywords] => 
    [category_id] => 23
    [category] => 22
    [subCategory] => 23
    [typeCategory] => 25
    [description] => 
    [fullTextAdvert] => 
    [price] => 
    [rooms_apartament] => 0
    [storey_apartament] => 0
    [addPost] => 
)
```

я хочу удалить все элементы до элемента [fullTextAdvert] включительно.
писать 8 раз (в данном массиве 8 первых элементов) unset($array['элемент']) нет смысла, потому что их может быть разное количество

Comment: А сделать так в цикле не вариант?

Comment: каким образом это можно сделать в цикле? я не знаю например!

Comment: Можно и без явного цикла, хотя быстрее работать не будет: `$arr = array_slice($arr, array_search('fullTextAdvert', array_keys($arr)) + 1, null, true);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно как-то так.

```
$array = [
    'title' => '',
    'keywords' => '',
    'category_id' => 23,
    'category' => 22,
    'subCategory' => 23,
    'typeCategory' => 25,
    'description' => '',
    'fullTextAdvert' => '', 
    'price' => '',
    'rooms_apartament' => 0,
    'storey_apartament' => 0,
    'addPost' => ''
];

// Проходим по массиву
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    unset($array[$key]);              // Удаляем элемент...
    if ($key == 'fullTextAdvert') {   // Но если ключ равен fullTextAdvert, то прекращаем
        break;
    }
}

print_r($array);
```

*Выведет:*

```
Array
(
    [price] => 
    [rooms_apartament] => 0
    [storey_apartament] => 0
    [addPost] => 
)
```

Comment: спасибо за идею

Comment: @vkt, не за что:)

Answer (score 1):

Можно выбирать значения из массива от указанного ключа с помощью array_walk():

```
$array = [
    'title' => '',
    'keywords' => '',
    'category_id' => 23,
    'category' => 22,
    'subCategory' => 23,
    'typeCategory' => 25,
    'description' => '',
    'fullTextAdvert' => '', 
    'price' => '',
    'rooms_apartament' => 0,
    'storey_apartament' => 0,
    'addPost' => ''
];

array_walk($array, function($item, $k)use(&$new) {
    static $switch = false;
    $k != 'fullTextAdvert' ?: $switch = true;
    !$switch ?: $k == 'fullTextAdvert' ?: $new[$k] = $item;
}, $array);
```

Результат будет в переменной $new.

Comment: я сначала тоже так подумал, НО как я уже писал первых элементов может быть не 8 а 7 или 6. это только в этом примере первых элементов именно 8. и мне нужно не выбрать 8 первых элементов а наоборот их исключить из массива, удалить

Comment: @vkt вам нужно удалить всё сначала массива и до ключа fullTextAdvert включительно?  _я не правильно написал пример_

Comment: да, мне нужно удалить

Comment: спасибо, нужно будет ознакомиться с функцией array_walk()

Comment: @Эдуард, К примеру, `&$new`.. Это какая-то ссылка на переменную..?

Comment: @entithat да, это ссылка в глобальную область видимости. Если такой переменной не существует, то после выполнения функции, она будет создана.

Comment: @Эдуард, отлично, теперь буду знать. Благодарю :)

Comment: @entithat да так-то не за что :)